# Mongoose update is not writing to the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've already been trying all solutions I found on stack overflow but none worked in my case.

My Issue:
I wan't to save/rewrite a complete document that was edited inside my CMS.
Therefore I'm passing the changed document from my angular app to the express middleware. Until this point everything works just as expected.

When I now try to update the document, I get {... nModified : 0 ...} back.

```
app.put('/page', function(req,res){

  page.update({_id : JSON.parse(req.query.update)._id},
    {
      'title' : JSON.parse(req.query.update).title,
      'page' : JSON.parse(req.query.update).page,
      'identifier' : JSON.parse(req.query.update).identifier,
      'hasSubmenu' : JSON.parse(req.query.update).hasSubmenu
    },
    function(err, numEffected){
      if(err) return handleError(err)
      res.send(numEffected);
    })
})
```

I also tried to use page.findById, modify and save(), but nothing worked out. The modified document had the correct values but once I hit save nothing gets written to the db.

Comment: Show us value of `req.query.update`

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the schema I am using was not updated after we changed something inside our app logic. For that reason the validation failed.